# Unable to find AWS Wrangler 2.10.0 Layer in US-WEST-2 under public-artifacts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-data-wrangler

Please consider the example shown in the below link:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/issues/923

I am trying to get the public artifacts bucket wrangler to US-West-2, but I am unable to find that, can someone help me figure it out, also, I want to create a wrangler layer in the same region.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Wrangler public artefacts bucket only exists in the us-east-1 region. However, the library is available in the us-west-2 region as [managed layer](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#aws-lambda-layer) and via [SAR](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#serverless-application-repository-sar)